# Is std::lower_bound free from race conditions

Tags: c++, c++11, openmp, std

Is it safe to run `std::lower_bound` on a shared vector object in an OpenMP loop? (using C++11)

Here is a basic example (edited from my code, not sure if it actually runs or not)

```
// fill range
std::vector<size_t> range;
range.reserve(r_len);
for (size_t i=0; i < r_len; i++) {
        range.push_back(i);
}
# pragma omp parallel for
for (size_t i=0; i<a_len; i++) {
    double x = //... some calculation
    auto lower = std::lower_bound(range.begin(), range.end(), x);
    size_t ind = std::distance(range.begin(), lower);
}
```

Comment: Please show a [example]. Are both threads running `std::lower_bound` on the same range?

Comment: can you define what "safe" means in this context? Guaranteed to return the correct result if the same object is access from other contexts? Guaranteed to return a result that *was* correct at some point in time if other contexts modify contents, but not the length of the std::vector? Guaranteed to not read uninitialized or freed memory if other context modify the container's length?

Comment: You can have multiple concurrent executions of `std::lower_bound` on the same collection, because `std::lower_bound` does not mutate the collection (to have compiler-enforced certainty, pass `cbegin/cend`-iterators to `std::lower_bound`). You obviously *mustn't* mutate the collection concurrently.

Comment: Yes, I'm using lower_bound to perform a binary search on a range. The range is not changed during the searches.

Answer (score 2):

Well, using `std::lower_bound` is safe in the sense that it does not modify the vector so you can call it concurrently and get the correct result as long as nothing else modifies the vector.